# Strange behavior in R - Add value in a cell to a newly created row

Tags: r

I'm working in a code that everything was running fine, but when I put some value bigger than 4, an error occurs (error = new columns would leave holes after existing columns).

To simplify I made this code to reproduce this strange behavior.

```
strange <- function(number = 1, order = 1) {
    df <- data.frame(0, order, NA)
    colnames(df) <- c(number, "order", "diff")
    #Next line throws an error when number > 4
    df[nrow(df) + 1, number] <- 1
    print(paste0("Number ", number, " ran fine"))
    return(df)
}

for (i in 1:10) df <- strange(number = i)
```

While typing this question I figure out how to stop the error, but I don't understand why `strange()` only works if number <= 4.

To work with any number I just changed to:

```
df[nrow(df) + 1, as.character(number)] <- 1
```

Comment: You used number as a column name, so it gets converted to character. However, you try to access the column by the numeric index. This works naturally for numbers 1:3, and for number 4 a new column "V1" is created. However, if number gets above 4, you ask R to create a fifth column when there is no fourth.

Comment: `df=data.frame(x=1:2);df[1,3]=1` produces the same error. The column name doesn't affect it. When rows are skipped with an assignment get `NA` are produced as fills, but when columns are skipped, an error is produced.